# Check if String[index] is empty before throwing ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

This probably is a silly question but I am missing something and just can't figure out what... Looking for a sensible way of checking whether given index exists or not in a `String[]` array

String is a representation of a K,V pair but sometimes V may be empty so possible string examples are:

Foo1:Bla1
Foo2:Bla2
Foo3:
Foo4:Bla4

```
public void constructPair(String string) {
    String[] split = string.split(":");
    ...
    if(split[index] != null) { } // nope
    if(!split[index].isEmpty() || !split[index].isBlank() { } //nope
    if(split[index].length() > 1) { } // nope
    ...
}
```

Or should i just wrap the whole thing in `try {} catch() {}` ? block and deal with the exception accordingly?

Edit: For clarity `'index'` is just pseudo not actual variable name

Comment: What is `index`? Is it pseudo-code or an actual variable?

Comment: @Gendarme just pseudo

Comment: How about 1st check `if (index<split.length)` and then if `if(split[index] != null)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array indices range from `0` to `length-1`, and they always exist. As long as `index >= 0` and `index < split.length`, `split[index]` will not throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

So simply add an if statement to check this:

```
if(index >=0 && index < split.length) {
    [...]
}
```